Back and Forward buttons not behaving as expected. the buttons cycle correctly but when using only buttons places text at the end. using keyboard ok
This codes behavior is unexpected when you use only the buttons to place chars from the carrot location. It always places the char at the end of the string.  If i use the buttons and place the char with the keyboard it does work as expected.  Why does this happen and any help with a solution is greatly appreciated.


function getInputSelection(el) {
  var start = 0,
    end = 0,
    normalizedValue, range,
    textInputRange, len, endRange;
  if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
    start = el.selectionStart;
    end = el.selectionEnd;
  } else {
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    if (range && range.parentElement() == el) {
      len = el.value.length;
      normalizedValue = el.value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
      textInputRange = el.createTextRange();
      textInputRange.moveToBookmark(range.getBookmark());
      endRange = el.createTextRange();
      endRange.collapse(false);
      if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("StartToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
        start = end = len;
      } else {
        start = -textInputRange.moveStart("character", -len);
        start += normalizedValue.slice(0, start).split("\n").length - 1;
        if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("EndToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
          end = len;
        } else {
          end = -textInputRange.moveEnd("character", -len);
          end += normalizedValue.slice(0, end).split("\n").length - 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return {
    start: start,
    end: end
  };
}

function setBack() {
  document.getElementById('user').value =
    document.getElementById('user').value.substring(0,
      document.getElementById('user').value.length - 1);
}


function moveBack(elId) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(elId);
  elem.setSelectionRange(elem.value.length,
    getInputSelection(elem).start - 1);
  elem.focus();
}

function moveForward(elId) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(elId);
  elem.setSelectionRange(elem.value.length,
    getInputSelection(elem).start + 1);
  elem.focus();
}
function focusElem(){
var foo =document.getElementById('user');
foo.focus();
}

function setA(){ document.getElementById('user').value += "A"; focusElem();}
function setB(){ document.getElementById('user').value += "B"; focusElem();}
function setC(){ document.getElementById('user').value += "C"; focusElem();}
function setD(){ document.getElementById('user').value += "D"; focusElem();}
<input id="user" type="text">
<button type="button" onclick="setBack();">backspace</button>
<button type="button" onclick="moveBack('user')">back</button>
<button type="button" onclick="moveForward('user')">forward</button>


<div>
<button type="button" onclick="setA()">A</button>
<button type="button" onclick="setB()">B</button>
<button type="button" onclick="setC()">C</button>
<button type="button" onclick="setD()">D</button>
<div>



Thanks for your time in advance!

Your helper functions do not respect the caret position
Here is a version that uses delegation and data-attributes to not have inline event handlers


window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const elem = document.getElementById("user");

  function insertCharAtCaret(char) {
    var selection = getInputSelection(elem);
    var startPos = selection.start;
    var endPos = selection.end;

    elem.value = elem.value.substring(0, startPos) + char + elem.value.substring(endPos);

    // Set the caret position after the inserted character
    elem.setSelectionRange(startPos + 1, startPos + 1);
    elem.focus();
  }

  function setBack() {
    var selection = getInputSelection(elem);
    var startPos = selection.start;
    var endPos = selection.end;

    // Only proceed if there's something to delete
    if (startPos > 0) {
      // Remove the character before the caret or the selected text
      elem.value = elem.value.substring(0, startPos - 1) + elem.value.substring(endPos);

      // Set the caret position after the deletion
      elem.setSelectionRange(startPos - 1, startPos - 1);
      elem.focus();
    }
  }

  function moveBack() {
    var start = getInputSelection(elem).start - 1;
    elem.setSelectionRange(start, start);
    elem.focus();
  }

  function moveForward() {
    var start = getInputSelection(elem).start + 1;
    elem.setSelectionRange(start, start);
    elem.focus();
  }

  // Delegation for character buttons
  document.getElementById("buttonContainer").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    const tgt = event.target.closest('button');
    if (!tgt || !tgt.dataset.char) return; // not a button or no char specified
    insertCharAtCaret(tgt.dataset.char);
  });

  const actions = {
    setBack,
    moveBack,
    moveForward,
  };

  document.getElementById("controlContainer").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    const tgt = event.target.closest('button');
    if (!tgt || !tgt.dataset.action) return; // not a button or no action specified

    const actionFunc = actions[tgt.dataset.action];
    if (actionFunc) {
      actionFunc();
    }
  });

  function getInputSelection(el) {
    var start = 0,
      end = 0,
      normalizedValue, range, textInputRange, len, endRange;
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number" && typeof el.selectionEnd == "number") {
      start = el.selectionStart;
      end = el.selectionEnd;
    } else {
      range = document.selection.createRange();
      if (range && range.parentElement() == el) {
        len = el.value.length;
        normalizedValue = el.value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
        textInputRange = el.createTextRange();
        textInputRange.moveToBookmark(range.getBookmark());
        endRange = el.createTextRange();
        endRange.collapse(false);
        if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("StartToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
          start = end = len;
        } else {
          start = -textInputRange.moveStart("character", -len);
          start += normalizedValue.slice(0, start).split("\n").length - 1;
          if (textInputRange.compareEndPoints("EndToEnd", endRange) > -1) {
            end = len;
          } else {
            end = -textInputRange.moveEnd("character", -len);
            end += normalizedValue.slice(0, end).split("\n").length - 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return {
      start: start,
      end: end
    };
  }
});
<input id="user" type="text">

<div id="controlContainer">
  <button type="button" data-action="setBack">backspace</button>
  <button type="button" data-action="moveBack">back</button>
  <button type="button" data-action="moveForward">forward</button>
</div>

<div id="buttonContainer">
  <button type="button" data-char="A">A</button>
  <button type="button" data-char="B">B</button>
  <button type="button" data-char="C">C</button>
  <button type="button" data-char="D">D</button>
</div>




It adds characters but keeps deleting from the end when deleting.

Updated to handle the caret in the setback too

@mplungjan thanks.  It works perfectly as expected.  "Your helper functions do not respect the caret position" says it all.  Thank you again.

I have updated it a little bit. No need to get the user element in each function
